# python: update (source newer than destination or destination missing) copy files

Tags: python, file, copy, updates

Is there a ready tool in python to update copy files? "Update copy" means that a copy should only be made if the source file is newer than the destination or if the destination file is missing, i.e. equivalent of the Linux `cp -u` command.

I understand that I could write the code myself by checking for existence of each destination file and by checking the time-stamps of both the source and the destination files and comparing them, but I do not want to "invent the bicycle" (i.e. invent something that has already been invented a long time ago) here if such a tool already exists.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distutils` module can do this.

For example, to update all files in directory `b` that have changed in directory `a`:

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
copy_tree("a", "b", update=1)
```

Not very helpfully, this will return a list of all files in `b` that are also in `a` whether they were updated or not (that is, if file `x` is in both directories, it will be in the list even if it didn't need updating).

You could also use:

```
from distutils.file_util import copy_file
copy_file('src', 'dst', update=1)
```

which will at least return a useful tuple:

```
('dst', 1)
```

with `1` indicating the file was updated, or `0` if not. (that is, the value is truthy, but not necessarily a `bool`).